# I am getting syntax errors on my while loop and switch statement and am confused as to why

Tags: java, for-loop, if-statement, while-loop, switch-statement

I am getting syntax errors on my while loop and switch statement which I have not gotten before when using this syntax.

I have tried using various different formats for my loop and my switch statement. It  still provides a syntax error
The error message reads "Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)"
and "Syntax error on token "case", assert expected".

```
   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("Please enter a number between 1 and 14. I will 
then tell you the playing card assosiated with it.");
   int x = intput.nextInt();
   while(1<x<=14){
     Switch(x){
       case 1:
         System.out.println("Your card is an Ace.");
         break;
       case 2:
         System.out.println("Your card is a two.");
         break;
       case 3:
         System.out.println("Your card is a three.");
         break;
       case 4:
         System.out.println("Your card is a four.");
         break;
       case 5:
         System.out.println("Your card is a five.");
         break;
       case 6:
         System.out.println("Your card is a six.");
         break;
       case 7:
         System.out.println("Your card is a seven.");
         break;
       case 8:
         System.out.println("Your card is an eight.");
         break;
       case 9:
         System.out.println("Your card is a nine.");
         break;
       case 10:
         System.out.println("Your card is a ten.");
         break;
       case 11:
         System.out.println("Your card is an Ace.");
         break;
       case 12:
         System.out.println("Your card is a Jack.");
         break;
       case 13:
         System.out.println("Your card is a Queen.");
         break;
       case 14:
         System.out.println("Your card is a King.");
         break;
     }
     System.out.println("Please enter a number between 1 and 14. I will 
then tell you the playing card assosiated with it.");
     x = input.nextInt();
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: What was the compiler error? 
The compiler issues errors for a reason.

Comment: These are all the errors i received, i got an error for all of my cases. File: C:\Users\danwr\Downloads\Lab7_1.java  [line: 7]
Error: Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)
File: C:\Users\danwr\Downloads\Lab7_1.java  [line: 9]
Error: Syntax error on token "case", assert expected
File: C:\Users\danwr\Downloads\Lab7_1.java  [line: 12]
Error: Syntax error on token "case", assert expected
File: C:\Users\danwr\Downloads\Lab7_1.java  [line: 15]
Error: Syntax error on token "case", assert expected

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing in java: `while(1<x<=14)`. You can only compare two numbers at a time, so you would have to write: `while(1 < x && x <= 14)` instead.

Comment: It still is giving me the same syntax error